# How to modify A* so that it takes into account the number of movement point left?

Tags: path-finding

Context : turn based game, grid system

Let this graph here :

```
(A)-2-(B)-1-(C)
 |    /|   /
 1  2  2  1
 | /   |/
(D)-1-(E)
```

My unit is at A and wants to go at C. He currently has 1 point left, therefore he cannot go onto tile B until next turn.

A*star could say that the best path is A-B-C and say that the next move is go to B. But my unit cannot. It should've gone to D, as it would move closer to C and use all of its remaining movement point.

Right now, I have done a workaround in which I give a set of tiles to ignore, these tiles are neighbouring tiles that cannot be access given a number of movement point left. This works OK because my tiles either cost 1 or 2 MP, and my units have a maximum of 2 MP.

I would like something that is more general.

I have currently thought of something. I will now stop adding tiles to the frontier for which the cost so far is superior to my current movement point left. Once the frontier is empty, I iterate over all the already seen tiles and select the one with the best heuristic and get the path from there. Would that work?

Comment: "Would that work?" don't take a stranger's word for it: try it and find out!

Comment: Why not consider the MP as part of the heuristic? You could define a constraint based on the number of MP available and the path cost until that point.